# What weeniest single future change can merge contiguous states of the USA?

Tags: alternate-reality, united-states

I am asking about the future, not past.  At least every year, someone proposes merger of these abutting US states. Common examples are

- [North + South Dakotas](https://hot975fm.com/what-if-north-dakota-and-south-dakota-merged-into-one-state/),
- [Virginia + West Virginia](https://www.quora.com/If-you-could-merge-any-two-US-states-which-would-you-merge-and-why/answer/Bob-Garey-2),
- [North + South Carolinas](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/55274/why-are-there-two-carolinas-and-two-dakotas),
- [Montana +  Utah +  Wyoming](https://twitter.com/davidfrum/status/1276262934151380993), because ["the existence of a national park between the borders of those two states makes it virtually impossible to control the border if it ever became necessary (e.g., during a plague outbreak)."](https://www.quora.com/If-you-could-merge-any-two-US-states-which-would-you-merge-and-why/answer/Brian-Collins-56)
- [New England states](https://www.burlingtonfreepress.com/story/opinion/my-turn/2015/05/04/opinion-merge-small-states/26740635/)  - CT, MA, ME, NH,  RI, VT.

But what can be the lone wee  catalyst? Currently I cannot forecast any benefit or catalyst, because

1. if any two states merge, ["both states would lose power in the Senate"](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskAnAmerican/comments/r1u10u/why_not_merge_some_us_states_together/hm177j8/) and [in the House of Representatives](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskAnAmerican/comments/r1u10u/why_not_merge_some_us_states_together/hm1g1ep/).
2. [some merger candidates are polarized in politics](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskAnAmerican/comments/r1u10u/why_not_merge_some_us_states_together/hm0tsa8/) - VA is more Democrat than  WV.

Your change must be realistic — no deus ex machina! Don't just assume that the weaker state's residents  all emigrate to the mightier state, or some precious resource is  unearthed in the weaker state.

Comment: This question could have many different answers. Is there any way you could give a little more explanation of the setting and the circumstances taking place?

Comment: I doubt that there will ever be a reunification of North and South Dakota while I live, the North is just too hostile. It has something like x20 the nuclear weapons of South Dakota. They show no indication of wanting to become one people again.

Comment: Also, point of order, many of these combinations wouldn't lose representation in the House, since their combined population is the sum of their separate populations (excepting rounding errors). Now, they would see their congressional districts rejiggered, and gerrymandering is always a nasty business.

Comment: So you ask for *any* bordering state combination as a result of *any* particular future event ? vtc along.. there are a million answers, we can't invent your story for you.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is a request for an infinite list of things: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6139#6139 -- Narrow it down to *specific* states and give some constraints on what you mean by 'small change', and this is definitely on topic, but not as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Nevada Rule

There is a law that treats one or more states differently.  For many years the federal government banned sports gambling in every state except Nevada, Delaware, Oregon and Montana.  This was a federal law that restricted states. It was later struck down but it was in effect for 26 years. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_and_Amateur_Sports_Protection_Act_of_1992

In the future there may be a law that treats some states more favorably, due to possession of some feature.  Lets say green energy tax credits for former states based on coal reserves.  Getting paid to leave the coal in the ground.  WV Qualifies but VA doesn't.  The government doesn't want to give it to every state, but if you start merging them...

## Succession and Reintegration

The Great Lutheran Khanate organizes and succeeds from the US and manages to convince the states of North and South Dakota to form the core.  After several prosperous decades as one united country with no internal borders they run out of tuna for hot dish.  As a result of being land locked they decide to rejoin the US.  As the former border has become meaningless they are accepted as a single state.

Comment: Would they have to smuggle in the dried Cod for Lutefisk?

Answer (score 5):

The US constitution says something about changing the number of states in the USA.

Article Four, Section Three, Clause One says:

> New States may be admitted by the Congress into this Union; but no new States shall be formed or erected within the Jurisdiction of any other State; nor any State be formed by the Junction of two or more States, or parts of States, without the Consent of the Legislatures of the States concerned as well as of the Congress.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Four_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_1:_Admission_of_new_states

So changing the number of states, or the sizes of states, is perfectly possible as long as the federal congress and the legislatures of any previously existing states that are changed all agree to the change.

Suppose that a new political party arises in the USA that wants to punish the states that revolted in 1861-1865.  Suppose that it gains control of the Federal government and the governments of the southern states.

Then they can declare that since the Federal government foolishly declined to execute, imprison for life, fine, or exile, every single official of the rebel government and every single member of the rebel armed forces, and since they have all died of natural causes since then and cannot be punished now, that the only surviving "persons" responsible for the Rebellion, the rebellious states, must be punished by being abolished and replaced by totally new states.

So North and South Caroline could be abolished and replaced by East and West Carolina, including large parts of Georgia.  Tennessee could be split up with east Tennessee being united with western parts of Virginia, North Carolina, etc. to form Appalachia.  West Tennessee could unite with  northern parts of Mississippi and Almabama to form a new state.  The southern parts of Mississippi and Alabama could unite with the eastern parts of Louisiana and the western parts of Florida to form the state of West Florida. What is left of Florida and Georgia would form East Florida.

During the Rebellion the Federal government formed a new Virginia state government in northern Virginia, but it abandoned that government when Viginia was readmitted to the Union. So the present state of Virginia could be abolished and the former government in north Viginia could be revived and take control of all of present Virginia except for the region that becomes part of Appalachia.

So present day 1) Virginia, 2) Tennessee, 3) North Carolina, 4) South carolina, 5) Georgia, 6) Florida, 7) Alabama, 8) Mississippi would now form: 1) North Virginia, 2) West carolina, 3) East Carolina, 4) East Florida, 5) West Florida, 6) west Tennessee/north Misissippi/north Alabama (I can't think of a catchy name for it) and 7) Appalachia.

West of the Mississippi western Louisiana, eastern Texas, and southern Arkansas might be formed into the state of Texarkana, and the rest of Arkansas might become Ozarkia.  Western Texas might be given to New Mexico.  But considering how large Texas is a big remnant of it would probably remain as Texas, so there wouldn't be a reduction in state numbers there.

Apart from abolishing the Rebel states my main interest in changing states is more likely to to increase their numbers.  Apparently the Cherokee have the largest population of any Indian nation, 316,000 enrolled members and 819,000 claiming Cherokee ancestry., so their reservations in Oklahoma could form a state with a relatively decent population.  The other Indian reservations in Oklahama could form a state.

The Navajo have 399,494 enrolled tribal members.  So their reservation could also be a low population state.  One problem is that the Hopi reservation is surrounded by the Navajo reservation so the desire of the Hopi to become part of the Navajo state or remain in Arizona would have to be honored.

Another problem is the Four Corners area where Utah, Arizona, New Mexico, and Colorado meet at a point. At the present time the Navajo reservation includes the corner parts of Arizona, New Mexico, and Utah, I think, so if the entire Navajo reservation became a separate state there would no longer be a Four Corners.   So maybe each of the affected states could retain a square mile at the Four corners to keep it the Four Corners, or even a mile wide corridor leading to the Four Corners.

So a small part of the Navajo reservation would remain outside of the new Navajo state and under the administrations of other states. But at the present time all of the Navajo reservation is part of several states and it seems to work all right, so such a change would actually simplyfy the adminstration of the Navajo lands.

And I could imagine making eastern South Dakoka merge with North Dakota to form Dakota.  Western South Dakota would be named the state of Lakota, after the Lakota or Teton Sioux.  Of course the problem for the Lakota, or Teton Sioux, would be they would still be a minority in the new State of Lakota.  The Black HIlls were taken in 1877, and the Great Sioux Reservation was broken up in 1890, most of the land being sold to white settlers.  Thus it would take a long process of buying land from white persons willing to sell to eventually make the Lakota the majority population in the state of Lakota.

The only process I can think of for mergering a number of smaller states into larger states is if the majority of the population in low population states decides that they have an unfair advantage in the Senate and the Electoral College and unselfishly decides to merge low population states to reduce that advantage in the Senate and the Electoral College.

Anyway, those are my thoughts on the hypothetical process of changing the number of states in the USA.

Comment: Please use a cool big ass header like the other answers. Don't be modest!

Comment: While I 100% agree with the logic of your answer, it's worth noting that the U.S. *did* punish the Confederates. Under the 14th Amendment, they were all disenfranchised (i.e., “you don't get to hold public offices”). It's actually a major part of Southern history; pissed-off-ness at this combined with the Carpetbaggers and Scalawags was what caused the formation of organizations such as the KKK and the White League.

Comment: @The Daleks  I just looked the 4th amendment.   Section 2 states than persons can be denied the vote for participation in rebelllion or other crime, but doesn't mandate it.  Section 3 disqualifies some rebels from holding elective or appointive federal or state offices, those who swore oaths to uphold the constitution and then joined the rebellion.  It left the vast amjority of ordinary rebels unaffected.

Answer (score 4):

Make the states to be confederations of smaller units. What made the states powerful in the US was how they were originally formed: as colonies encompassing large land areas. The Virginia Colony was granted huge amount of land to conquer.

If, on the other hand, the colony charter simply covered a small area, other colonies started nearby, and states were formed by confederation of these smaller areas, then the smaller areas could withdraw from the confederation and join another. We could wind up with northern New Jersey leaving the state and joining the state formed by New York City leaving New York.

You may also look at why areas would want to leave a state. While most of the current noise is political, the real issues will be trade and trade barriers. Currently, we do not have any major trade barriers between states. If you add a trade barrier, then trading areas will have good reason to join together.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I was asking for future change, not historical.

Comment: @VitaliToi if the answer is not to your satisfaction, do not use the green checkmark. Also, using the green checkmark too early (within a few hours) will not be an incentive for future answers.

Comment: @VitaliToi Any future change has to consider the past and why the states are so powerful. It is that past that makes a future change so difficult. You need to figure out what would change the political power structure. Because the past influences the present so much, you would need to have something that is stronger than the past, such as a massive pandemic that wipes out civilization. Even then, there might be a memory of the past keeping people in states.

Comment: @VitaliToi For thousands of years, political strength has been built on control of natural resources. In most cases, that meant control of land areas and taking the results of labor from those who worked the land (via taxes or slavery). This structure is codified in the laws that built up the states. For two states to merge, someone will lose political power in one of the states. It isn't the US Senate or House of Representatives that is important, it is in the state capital that loses the Governor, Lt. Gov., and state representatives. That is why it won't happen. You have to change that loss.

Answer (score 2):

## In your world, States were never powers of their own

The only change you need is that the founding fathers took a different route of federalism: under their constitution, the states are not empowered to do anything without federal approval and they have much less power. They are just subparts of the USA, and the federal level can legislate and restructure them as they want. If the President says, that the states are dissolved, then that's it, they are. They only exist because they offer a good means to distribute money and seat people in the senate by them.

Elections for the federal level are not summed at the state level in between, but every county or block of them directly votes their representatives into the federal institutions. As a result, merging and splitting states will not impact a state negatively but for stopping to exist.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I was asking for future change, not historical.

Answer (score 2):

The US is made up of 50 states. To represent these, there are 50 stars on the flag. There are also 13 stripes on the flag, to represent the original 13 colonies. However, this was not always the case.

If you look at the flag that we had during the War of 1812, famous enough that it was mentioned in our National Anthem, it has 15 stars and 15 stripes. The flag back then gained both a star and a stripe for each state, and this was the case until 1818, with the addition of Mississippi making 20 states in the union. (Curiously, the largest number of stripes was 16, and even that was an unofficial flag only ever found in Tennessee.)

[image: The Star Spangled Banner flag.]

However, a relatively simple change would allow a good reason for them to combine states: They kept adding stripes, and in 1960-something the Government decided to combine states to keep the stripe total lower. This, while being a slight historical change, doesn't change much about the government, other than the different state lines.

Answer (score 1):

### Frame Challenge

The easiest way for it to happen (because it happens anyway) is a Civil War (or War Between the States, depending on where you're from.)

Before the Civil War, people viewed the United *States* similarly to how we view the European Union. It was "the United States *are*", not "the United States *is*." This was officially codified in the 10th Amendment ("The powers not delegated to the United States by the Constitution, nor prohibited by it to the States, are reserved to the States respectively, or to the people.") The federal government ruled the states in their interactions with each other and foreign states, while the states ruled their respective citizens.

As a result of the Civil War, the U.S. of A. became truly one nation. State divisions are still technically a thing, but the federal government rules people directly (as opposed to ruling the states as it did antebellum), making them mostly redundant.

**EDIT:**

I re-read your question, and it appears you want the states to merge *in the future*. There are two ways you could do that.

The "simplest" solution is to just delay the civil war. However, that's not reasonable; while slavery was the official thing that started the war<sup>[1]</sup>, the root cause was the conflict between two different political worldviews, regionalism and nationalism. In other words, was the US to be a bunch of little countries or one big country? The slavery issue just happened to be the particular issue around which the sides polarized. Had slavery been resolved peacefully, it would have been tariffs (which Marx insisted was the real cause anyway), Westward Expansion, or a number of other things.

The harder (but less handwave-y) way is to have President Hayes not be elected. Here's the general idea:

1. Immediately after Hayes was elected, the Democrats started yelling “tHe ElEcTiOn WaS sToLeN!!!!!” <sup>Arguably, it was.</sup>
2. To make them shut up, he promised to immediately end the Reconstruction on terms favorable to the South.
3. Up until that point, Congress was considering radically reorganizing the Southern states (up to and including making them territories in perpetuity, like Puerto Rico).
4. While somewhat unlikely, it's not unreasonable that Congress would have kept the Southern states as territories until the near future.
5. When it reintegrates them, they would almost certainly be combined as much as possible, to limit the number of Southern seats in the Senate. For example, Louisiana and Mississippi would become one state.

---

<sup>[1]: Technically it was actually Pres. Lincoln engineering an incident at Fort Sumter so that he could *cough* "un-divide" the American House. However, slavery was what caused the secession that made it necessary in his eyes in the first place.</sup>

Comment: thanks but "the "simplest" solution is to just delay the civil war." this does not feel realistic. why do you forecast a 2nd US civil war?

Comment: @VitaliToi I don't. I was saying that "delay the civil war", while supremely unrealistic, is a more or less common trope.

Answer (score 1):

### A Major Nuclear Meltdown in Rhode Island

I don't think any State would willing allow itself to be merged with another state... not because they are bad neighbors or anything, but because this dilutes thier power in the senate.  This means in order to get 2 states to merge, you need an event that gives other states the grounds to challenge its right to exist.  Challenging the right of a State to exist it a pretty big, but there is one law that could possibly be cited to make this possible: The Northwest Ordinance of 1787.

The Northwest Ordinance of 1787 set a population requirement of 60,000 free adult males before a territory could become a state. Leaving room for interpretation, the Supreme Court could perhaps be convinced to rule that this law also means that a territory must maintain a population of 60,000 men to retain its statehood.  If some major calamity were to befall a state to drop it's adult male population under 60,000 men, then the other states might have the right to call for its disbandment... and rightfully so.  If another state only had 60,000 men (which means an estimated total population of 150,000), then you would have a very tiny number of people with a lot of relative power in the Senate.

Since all states now have a population of 579,000 or greater... this event can not be a small one... that is, unless the state is small enough that a single event could drive out most of the population.  Rhode Island has a total population of 1,059,000 in a landmass that is only 1,214 mi².  The Chernobyl disaster created an exclusion zone with a 19mi radius around the Chernobyl nuclear powerplant which forced people to evacuate a 1134 mi² area.  If a similarly disastrous meltdown were to happen in the Warwick area, it would force nearly the entire State to have to be evacuated leaving only tiny pockets of habitable areas perhaps around Westerly and Woonsocket dropping the state's total population to less than 100,000.

With Rhode Island no longer having the minimum population to claim statehood, and very little recourse to get its population back any time soon since the whole state is basically a giant radioactive disaster area, Rhode Island would likely be forced to merge with Connecticut and/or Massachusetts. Otherwise, they risk being downgraded to a territory and losing thier right to representation in the federal government all together.